# Microsoft Project Server 2019 on premise: ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException in Project Update queue job created using CSOM

Tags: ms-project, csom, project-server, sharepoint-2019

I have a code that makes a few simple changes to a project using CSOM:

```cs
    projContext.Load(this.projContext.Projects, pj => pj.Where(p => p.Id == projId));
    projContext.ExecuteQuery();
    
    var proj = projContext.Projects.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == projId);
    var draft = proj.CheckOut();
    
    projContext.Load(draft, p => p.Owner);
    projContext.ExecuteQuery();
    
    draft.Owner = managerUser;
    
    var tasks = draft.Tasks;
    projContext.Load(tasks, tsk => tsk.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(t => t.Id, t => t.StatusManager));
    projContext.ExecuteQuery();
    
    var newTaskId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var newTask = new PS.TaskCreationInformation {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "New task",
        StatusManager = managerUser,
    };
    tasks.Add(newTask);
    draft.Assignments.Add(new PS.AssignmentCreationInformation {
        TaskId = newTaskId,
        ResourceId = managerId,
    });
    
    var qJob = draft.Update();
    var jobState = projContext.WaitForQueue(qJob, TimeoutSeconds);
```

It works well in development environment, but the Update job in queue fails with internal exception in production environment. This happens only with projects that were created a certain way:

- Fresh enterprise project in PWA;
- Enterprise project created by importing a local project to server using Project Professional.

Here is the queue error:

> Your Project Update job failed. Its current state is failed. It was 0
> complete. It entered the queue on 12/08/2022 16:24:05 Error ID: 9133
> Error ID: 26000
>
> Detailed error below – send it to the administrator for more detailed
> troubleshooting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <errinfo><general><class name="Project"><error id="9133" name="ProjectSchedulingEngineException" uid="2d0b12df-fb76-ed11-95ef-005056b6871f" exception="System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException: The communication object,  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has  been Aborted. Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.ProjectEngineUpdate.UpdateProjectWithPCS(IPlatformContext context, ProjectDataSet dataset, Guid projectUid, Guid sessionUid, Boolean inVisibilitySyncMode, Boolean skipEventHandlers, Boolean skipPostSSPUpdate) at Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.BusinessLayer.ProjectMain.HandleProject2(MessageContext mContext, ProjectDataSet dataset, Guid projectUid, Guid sessionUid, Boolean inVisibilitySyncMode)" /></class><class name="Queue"><error id="26000" name="GeneralQueueJobFailed" uid="2e0b12df-fb76-ed11-95ef-005056b6871f" JobUID="c3f6fcdb-fb76-ed11-95ef-005056b6871f" ComputerName="7e53cc63-ebbd-427f-bde0-d1db317abacd" GroupType="ProjectUpdate" MessageType="ProjectUpdate2Message" MessageId="1" Stage="" CorrelationUID="704180a0-0676-40da-abac-d2a039c9acc3" /></class></general> </errinfo>
```

> You can do the following:
>
> 1. Try troubleshooting using the error IDs, error XML.
> 2. Contact administrator with your jobID (db6df25a-d4c1-4631-b7a1-2e7aae9f5c16) and error XML.

Tried to reproduce the problem on Project Server used for development, no luck yet. Looks like Microsoft is totally responsible for the issue, but maybe someone knows a workaround?